# FOSMessageBundle - Not generating entities properly

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using [FOSMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle), and I thought i followed the instructions pretty well, but i cant seem to get the database to generate properly...

Heres my Message entity:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Entity\Message as BaseMessage;
use FOS\MessageBundle\Model\ParticipantInterface;

/**
 * Message
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("All")
 */
class Message extends BaseMessage implements EntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     * @JMS\Groups({"list", "default"})
     * @JMS\Expose()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var Thread
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Thread", inversedBy="messages", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="thread_id")
     * @JMS\Groups({"default"})
     */
    protected $thread;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @var ParticipantInterface
     */
    protected $sender;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="MessageMetadata", mappedBy="message", cascade={"all"})
     * @var MessageMetadata
     */
    protected $metadata;
}
```

And my `config.yml`

```
fos_message:
    db_driver: orm
    thread_class: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Thread
    message_class: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Message
```

The issue is, my table ends up with only `id`, `thread_id`, and `sender_id`. Its missing the rest of the fields.

What am i missing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merk, one of the contributors to the project pointed me at setting `auto_mapping` to `true` under the entity manager.

Once i set this, it solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

check if all classes are correcly mapped :

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:info
```

if not you have to MessageMetadata to the config file

```
message_class: Acme\Bundle\DemoBundle\Entity\Message
```

Comment: this is showing that all my classes are mapped correctly, I also have the other tables and entities created, i just didnt post them. too much text...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but in your case it seems like you have two different configurations for this entity - your annotations and xml from `FOSCommentBundle`

Please change your configuration to XML format, like this https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/doctrine/Message.orm.xml and check again.

regards,

Comment: Their documentation asks you to use annotations, https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/01a-orm-models.md#message-class

Answer (score 0):

For me the auto_mapping did not work, I got the message

Unrecognized option "auto_mapping" under "doctrine.orm"

I solved the  issue by adding the FOSMessageBundle like this:

orm:

```
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
            connection: default
            second_level_cache:
                enabled: true
            mappings:
                AppBundle: ~
                UserBundle: ~
                FOSMessageBundle: ~
```