# FosMessageBundle not work

Tags: symfony

Im using [FosMessageBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSMessageBundle)

I step by step documentation, and i have my table ends up with only id, thread_id, and sender_id. Its missing the rest of the fields.

And when i want get thread or message count i controller i get error:

```
line 0, col 165 near 'isRead = :is': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\MessageMetadata has no field or association named isRead
```

isRead column isset in extend MessageMetaData class ... 
config.yml

```
fos_message:
db_driver: orm
thread_class: AppBundle\Entity\Thread
message_class: AppBundle\Entity\Message
```

controller: And entity which in documentation.

```
class MessageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/message/", name="message")
     */
    public function viewAction()
    {
    $provider = $this->get('fos_message.provider');

        $threads = $provider->getNbUnreadMessages();
        dump($threads);die;

    return $this->render('message/message.html.twig', ['message' => $threads]);

    }
```

Comment: Does anyone know a good resource for FOSMessageBundle? I am having a very hard time configuring it.

Comment: I recently ran into the same problem and am trying to get why doctrine does not create the inherited fields. I couldn't find any useful resources besides the documentation on github…

Answer (score 0):

It seems like doctrine will only correctly create the entities with all inherited fields when there is no error in your mapping/schema.

I tried checking if my mapping was ok as explained in this answer of a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21155874/3864997. This did not yield any errors, so i looked at the other commands doctrine provides.

I ran `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` and was informed that some mapping on other entities (they had no relation to the entities required for FOSMessageBundle) was invalid. This seemed funny to me, since the debug-bar in symfony did not show me those even though it showed me similar errors in the past.

I fixed those and then ran `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`. The output now included the statements to add the missing inherited fields to the database.